# Replacing different substrings without clear pattern in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace part of some queries (strings) which **don't** always have the same substring to replace.

```
query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
from table 
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), id """
```

I want to replace the part regarding date after *group by*.

This part could be any of the following strings:

```
'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), DAY(utimestamp),'
'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), WEEK(utimestamp),'
'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp),'
'YEAR(utimestamp),'
```

My idea is to search for "*(utimestamp),*" and get the part from the left (YEAR, DAY, WEEK or MONTH) searching for the first blank space in the left. After having those removed I want to insert another substring, but how can I insert this substring now that I have blank spaces where the new substring should go.

I thought of getting the index everytime I removed a string and once there's no more to remove insert the substring there but I think I'm complicating things.

Is there an easier, neat way of doing this? Am I missing something?

**EXAMPLE:**

Input string that needs replacement:

query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
    from table 
    where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
    group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), id """

or

```
query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
        from table 
        where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
        group by YEAR(utimestamp), id """
```

or

```
query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
        from table 
        where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
        group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), WEEK(utimestamp), id """
```

etc.

Desired result:

```
query_replaced = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
    from table 
    where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
    group by MY_COOL_STRING, id """
```

If should work for all those cases (and more, the ones stated before)

Following @Efferalgan answer I came up with this:

```
query_1 = query.split("group by")[0]
utimestamp_list = query.split("(utimestamp)")
l = len(utimestamp_list)
query_2 = utimestamp_list[l-1]
query_3 = query_1 + " group by MY_COOL_STRING" + query_2
```

Comment: Doesn't `query = query.split("group by")[0] + "group by" + whatever_text_you_want` do what you want? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Well, now that you say it I could do it that way. I need to add the last part at the end (in this case 'id').

Comment: Perhaps a full example would help people understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you asked, I would go for

```
query = query.split("group by")[0] + " group by MY_COOL_STRING" + query.split("(utimestamp)")[-1]
```

It concatenates the part before the `group by`, then `MY_COOL_STRING` and then first thing before the first `(utimestamp)`.

Comment: The problem is it's not just id what I could get at the end of the query, I could get "id, order by utimestamp asc" for example.

Comment: I mean I should keep the last part to concatenate again, but thanks to this question I found the solution. Let me make it neat so I can show you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It would be great if you could edit your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) of regex to achieve it:

```
>>> import re
>>> replace_with = 'HELLO'
>>> new_string  = re.sub('group by\s\w+\(utimestamp\)', "group_by"+replace_with, query)

# Value of new_string: SELECT  as utimestamp, sum(value) as value 
# from table 
# where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00' 
# group by HELLO, HELLO, id
```

where `replace_with` is the content you need to update with the pattern `'\w+\(utimestamp\)'` and `query` is the string you mentioned in the code.

Here, `\w+` means alphabets with occurence of one or more, whereas `\(utimestamp\)` along with that denotes, words followed by the string `(utimestamp)`.

**EDIT**:

As is mentioned in the comment, to replace all instances of the `timestamp` in the `query`, regex expression should be like:

```
re.sub('group by\s\w+\(utimestamp\)(,\s*\w+\(utimestamp\))*', "group_by" + replace_with, query)

# Returned Value:  
# SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value from table
# where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00'
# group by HELLO, id
```

Comment: I don't know how to use regex but I guess I'll need to learn it asap.

Comment: The result I'm looking for is: 

 SELECT  as utimestamp, sum(value) as value from table where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00'  **group by HELLO,**  id

Just remove every ocurrence of words followed by '(utimestamp)' and replace with HELLO (or wahtever string needed)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't want to get rid of the `(utimestamp)` part, only the `YEAR`, `MONTH`, etc. Or maybe I got it wrong but this solution is trivial to adapt in that case: just adapt the `rep` dict to cover your needs.

In any case, I would use regular expressions for that. This should take care of what you want (I think) in a single pass and in a (fairly) simple way.

```python
import re

rep = {
    'YEAR': 'y',
    'MONTH': 'm',
    'WEEK': 'w',
    'DAY': 'd',
}

query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value from table
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00'
group by YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), id """

rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
replaced = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], query)

print("Processed query: {}\n".format(replaced))
```

That's just the basic example. Here's a more complete one with comments explaining what the code does, including a test at the end for all the possible patterns you mentioned:

```python
import re

# Several possible patterns like you mentioned.
# Only used for testing further down.
patterns = [
    'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), DAY(utimestamp)',
    'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp), WEEK(utimestamp)',
    'YEAR(utimestamp), MONTH(utimestamp)',
    'YEAR(utimestamp)'
]

# These are the several patterns to be matched and their replacements.
# The keys are the patterns to match and the values are what you want
# to replace them with.
rep = {
    'YEAR': 'y',
    'MONTH': 'm',
    'WEEK': 'w',
    'DAY': 'd',
}

# The query string template, where we'll replace {} with each of the patterns.
query = """ SELECT DATE(utimestamp) as utimestamp, sum(value) as value from table
where utimestamp BETWEEN '2000-06-28 00:00:00' AND '2000-07-05 00:00:00'
group by {}, id """

# A dictionary with escaped patterns (the keys) suitable for use in regex.
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())

# We join each possible pattern (the keys in the rep dict) with | so that the
# regex engine considers them all when matching, i.e., "hey, regex engine,
# please match YEAR or MONTH or WEEK or DAY". This builds the matching patter
# we'll use and we also pre-compile the regex to make it faster.
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))

# This is the trick part: we're using pattern.sub() to replace our pattern from
# above with what we want (the values in the rep dict). We're telling the regex
# engine to call a function for each occurrence of the pattern in order to get
# the value we're replacing it with. In our case, we want to get the value from
# the rep dict, using the key which is the found match. m is the match object,
# m.group(0) is the first match, re.escape() escapes the value and we finally
# use this as the key to fetch the value from the rep dict.
q = query.format(patterns[0])
print("Query: {}\n".format(q))
replaced = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], q)
print("Processed query: {}\n".format(replaced))

# Now to test it with the examples you gave let's iterate over the patterns
# dict, form a new query string using each of them and run the regex against
# each one.
print("###########################")
print("Test each pattern:\n")
print("---------------------------")
for p in patterns:
    q = query.format(p)
    print("Pattern: {}".format(p))
    print("Original query: {}\n".format(q))

    replaced = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], q)
    print("Processed query: {}\n".format(replaced))
    print("---------------------------\n")
```

You can read more about how [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) works.

Comment: I added an example tha could explain it better.